# Recreating Twitter's slide in/out activity animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation, android-transitions

Twitter uses the following slide in/out animation when switching between activities:

https://gfycat.com/BountifulPoisedAyeaye

Notice that the previous activity moves back and fades, and then the next activity slides in from the right.

How can this animation be recreated?

Here is the code that I have that starts the next activity:

```
public void startSecondActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. Github link here:

https://gist.github.com/kwent/5875749

Answer (score 0):

You have to give animation to open and close `Activity`. add following two files inside res>anim folder.

enter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

exit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

then now you have to just do the following when you open `Activity` .

```
public void startSecondActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
}
```

Comment: This only does the slide animation. It doesn't do the rest (i.e. "Notice that the previous activity moves back and fades").